# How to set Jetty to use non-strict evaluation mode in Jexl?

Tags: jsp, jetty, jexl

We're trying to move a website built mostly from JSPs from Websphere to Jetty.  We're having a problem with `NullPointerException` evaluating EL code in `test` attributes:

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.domainSpecificName}">
```

The problem is that the `domainSpecificName` attribute is either set to true or not present in the request.

In Websphere this line is compiled to

```
_jspx_th_c_if_0.setTest(((java.lang.Boolean) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${requestScope.domainSpecificName}", boolean.class, (PageContext)pageContext, _jspx_fnmap, false)).booleanValue());
```

(Note the class is `boolean` and the default value is `false`.)

The same line of the JSP, in Jetty, compiles to

```
_jspx_th_c_if_0.setTest(((java.lang.Boolean) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.evaluateExpression("${requestScope.domainSpecificName}", java.lang.Boolean.class, (PageContext)_jspx_page_context, null)).booleanValue());
```

Here we have a class of `Boolean` and a default value of `null`, which obviously will throw a NPE if the attribute is not present.

From the documentation, it sounds like if we can set `JexlBuilder.strict(false)` it will not treat `null` values as errors.  (Although I'm not sure how that would be compiled.)

Does anyone know how to configure JexlBuilder inside Jetty?

Alternatively, if I'm heading down the wrong path; does anyone know the correct way to be handling this?  There are hundreds of instances of `<c:if test="${...}">` that might throw NPEs, so at least in the short term fixing them all is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

JSP Support in Jetty uses Apache Jasper, which uses Apache EL, which uses `javax.el`.

`javax.el` has no `JexlBuilder` style class.

Perhaps one of the Apache JSP or Apache EL system properties will help you.

See: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/systemprops.html

Comment: For whatever reason, it appears that our deployed instance is using the glassfish implementation of `javax.el` which doesn't seem to have those properties.  Thanks for your suggestion, though.

Comment: Then you have a very old and long out of date [version of Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html).  The Jetty project moved away from the Glassfish JSP implementation due to too many bugs about 7 years ago.